# Background shadow of the cursor changes on Textfield in Swift2

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Hello an unusual shadow is there where the cursor is placed please help me to remove it as seen at the screenshot .?
thanks in advance

```
        // set the shadow of view
        loginView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 255.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 0.6)
        loginView.layer.shadowRadius = 10
        loginView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0)
        loginView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        loginView.clipsToBounds = false
        self.loginView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3;

        loginView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        loginView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

here i set the delegate the of textfield

```
countryNameText.delegate = self
        countryNameText.tag = 1
        mobileNumberText.delegate = self
        mobileNumberText.tag = 2
```

this code is used to set gradient colour of view

```
func gradient() {
        let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = self.view.bounds
        gradient.colors = [UIColor(red: 26.0/255.0, green: 159.0/255.0, blue: 154.0/255.0, alpha: 0.2).CGColor,  UIColor(red: 26.0/255.0, green: 159.0/255.0, blue: 154.0/255.0, alpha: 0.5).CGColor , UIColor(red: 26.0/255.0, green: 159.0/255.0, blue: 154.0/255.0, alpha: 0.9).CGColor ]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)
    }
```

[image]

Comment: ok whats ur question now,, what the problem u faced

Comment: Are you using any custom Library Field or UITextField?

Comment: when i click on textfield then change colour of some part of view. u looking into pic

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: ya we seen, but what the output you expect

Comment: @NiravD no library is used

Comment: @IOS Singh in which function are you calling all this?

Comment: @TusharSharma i edit qustion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just remove this line I hope this will work for you !!

**loginView.layer.masksToBounds = true**